# Java:Do-while Loop, Even number then trying again

Tags: java, loops, while-loop, do-while

I can loop simply but it is hard for me to do even and odd numbers only. I want it like these for example:

Enter your number: *20*

2 4 6 8 10 12 14 16 18 20

Do you want to do it again? Yes/No?

My code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner input=new Scanner(System.in);
    String c = null;
    do {
        int i;
        System.out.println("Enter a Number:");
        int n = input.nextInt();

        for(i=1; i<n; i++) {
            System.out.println(i);
            if(n%2==0) {
                System.out.println(i + " " );

            }
            System.out.println("Try Again? Y/N");
            c = input.next();   

        }
    }while(c.equalsIgnoreCase("y"));
}
```

Comment: You need to copy/paste your code into your question, not link an image to the code. You're printing "Try Again?" every time through the loop. Is that what you want? You want that question *outside* (after) the loop is completed.

Comment: @lurker well it wouldn't look again if they put N, so that seems what they do want.

Comment: It looks like your code would work. Did you try it?

Comment: @corsiKa for the outer loop, yes. For the inner loop (where it is), no. I should have said "inner" loop in my first conment.

Comment: Hello. Please don't post text/code as image/link ([more info](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557)). Use [edit] option to correct your post.

Comment: Hello Friends iam a freshman means just learning programming on java and just started stackoveflow for some help today so i still dont know how to navigate this site, thank you for your information.. bad english sorry. @NomadMaker yes i did but not the way i want. 
i get this:
1
1
but i want this
2 4 6 8 10

Comment: You don't need to check the value. You could just do ``for(i = 1; i < n; i += 2) {...}``

Comment: @NomadMaker - If you want to do it this way, you need to start with `i = 2`.

Comment: @ArvindKumarAvinash You are correct. My fingers are so trained that despite what I wanted, I set i = 1. Of course, it was meant to be i = 2, but unless you could read my mind, nobody would know this. Thank you.

Comment: @NomadMaker - Ha ha ha...it happens with every one of us...Merry Christmas!

Comment: @ArvindKumarAvinash just what i wanted thank you..@NomadMaker thank you for the help friends even tho my english is bad. Merry X-mas to you all

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to check `i % 2 == 0` instead of `n % 2 == 0`.

**Demo:**

```
import java.util.Scanner;

class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        String c = null;
        do {
            System.out.print("Enter a Number: ");
            int n = input.nextInt();

            for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
                if (i % 2 == 0) {
                    System.out.print(i + " ");
                }
            }

            System.out.print("\nTry Again? Y/N: ");
            c = input.next();
        } while (c.equalsIgnoreCase("y"));
    }
}
```

**A sample run:**

```
Enter a Number: 20
2 4 6 8 10 12 14 16 18 20 
Try Again? Y/N: y
Enter a Number: 25
2 4 6 8 10 12 14 16 18 20 22 24 
Try Again? Y/N: n
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code is saying `if (n%2 == 0)` but the loop iterates over `i`. This `n` will never change in each loop.

It's probably not the only problem in your code, but certainly you should be looking at what `i` does in the loop instead of `n` on that line.

Comment: Enter a Number:
20
1
Try Again? Y/N
y
2
2 
Try Again? Y/N
y
3
Try Again? Y/N

just do that

Comment: there is a problem with my code but iam still learning thankyou for your help friend.